# Binary stars orbiting around each other are equidistant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, binary-stars

This is a problem that was given to me in my Classical Mechanics course:

> J.S.Plaskett's star is one of the most massive stars known at present. It is a binary star, that is, it consists of two stars bound together by gravity. From spectroscopic studies it is known that the period of revolution of each component is $14.4$ days and that the velocity of each component is about $220$ km/s. The orbit is nearly circular.

> (a) Argue that the masses of two stars are nearly equal and that they are nearly equidistant from the centre of mass of the system, and (b) compute the reduced mass and and the separation of the two components.

So my path forward was pretty clear: I simply assumed that the stars were orbiting around their center of mass and then used the simple equation $v = \frac{2\pi r}{T}$ to obtain the separation, and then used the fact that the COM satisfies $m_1r_1 = m_2 r_2$ to conclude.

I am not sure how to compute the reduced mass though - I know that in this case $\mu = \frac{m}{2}$ where $m$ is the mass of one of the stars, but I can't think of a way to get $m$ in the first place. Do we have to use energy considerations (or simplify the system into a one-body problem)?

Comment: Have you tried Wikipedia? Surely there is a article on the nonrelativistic two particle system in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument for the first part of the problem is good.

You know that the two orbital velocities and masses are the same.  Think of the two stars as masses on the ends of a lever.  Where do you need to put the fulcrum (the center of mass) to ensure that when the lever moves, the masses necessarily move at the same speed in opposite directions?